# Need help about OOP-design for sharing variables between classes, which run with a timer indipendently

Tags: c++, oop, timer, boost-asio

Let's say I have 2 classes **Fly** and **Bee**, which methods (respectively *run* and *loop*) runs at differents times.

```
/* Fly */
using namespace boost::asio 
using namespace boost::posix_time

class Fly { 
... 
deadline_timer timeout_fly_;
char text_fly_;

Fly::Fly( io_service &io): timeout_fly_(io, seconds(4) ) 
{ 
    timeout_fly_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Fly::run, this ) );   
}

Fly::run(void) 
{ 
    std::cout << "Running Fly forever" << std::endl;

     timeout_fly_.expires_at( timeout_fly_.expires_at() + seconds(4)));  
     timeout_fly_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Fly::run, this ) ); 
}
```

and:

```
/* Bee */
class Bee { 
... 
deadline_timer timeout_bar_; 
char text_bee_;

Bee::Bee(io_service &io): timeout_bee_(io, seconds(2) ) 
{ 
    timeout_bee_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Bee::loop, this ) );  
}

Bee::loop(void) 
{ 
     std::cout << "Running Bee forever" << std::endl;

     timeout_bee_.expires_at( timeout_bee_.expires_at() + seconds(2) );
     timeout_bee_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Bee::loop, this ) ); 
 }
```

which are started in the main like:

```
/* main.cpp */
io_service io_service;

while(1) {

    io_service.run();
}
```

Now I have the problem that I need to exchange some data between both classes (e.g. the char text ). But I stuck and cannot fix this problem because I don't know how to do that.

I was thinking about passing one class to the other as a *reference*:

```
using namespace boost::asio
using namespace boost::posix_time

class Fly {
...
  deadline_timer timeout_fly_;
  Bee bee_;
  char text_fly_;
...

  Fly::Fly(io_service &io, Bee &bee): timeout_fly_(io,seconds(4)), bee_(bee)
  {
    timeout_fly_.async_wait(boost::bind( &Fly::run, this));  
  }

  Fly::run(void)
  {
    std::cout << "Running Fly forever" << std::endl;

    text_fly_ = bee_->getTextInBee();

    timeout_fly_.expires_at(timeout_fly_.expires_at() + seconds(4));
    timeout_fly_.async_wait(boost::bind( &Fly::run, this));
  }
```

But I'm not sure that this is a good OOP-Design. Furhtermore it will complicate my program. I want to keep it as simple as possible.
Another option could be to create 2 different threads, let them run and save the results with a mutex to synchronize both threads.

How can I exchange generally Data between two classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I rewrote my code according to the following pattern.
It consists of a *wrapper class*, which creates at least three objects:

- one class of type Bee;
- one class of type Fly;
- one class to exhange data between both;

In the wrapper class I have something like the following:

```
/* Wrapper class */
class Insect {

    /* Class with methods and members for sharing data */
    Data *exchange_data = new Data;

    /* Generate Bee */
    Bee bee;
    /* Generate Fly */
    Fly fly;


    public:
      Insect( boost::asio::io_service &io )
             : bee(io, exchange_data), fly(io, exchange_data);

}
```

Note that the ***common shared_data class*** is now passed at the initialization list when the constructor of the class is called. The class is a member of the wrapper class and once created must be passed to both classes which now are a little bit different:

```
/* Fly */
using namespace boost::asio 
using namespace boost::posix_time

class Fly { 
... 
deadline_timer timeout_fly_;
char text_fly_;
Data *shared_data;

Fly::Fly( io_service &io, Data *data): timeout_fly_(io, seconds(4)), shared_data(data)
{ 
    timeout_fly_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Fly::run, this ) );   
}

Fly::run(void) 
{ 
    std::cout << "Running Fly forever" << std::endl;

    shared_data->setMember( "I write something here" );

    timeout_fly_.expires_at( timeout_fly_.expires_at() + seconds(4)));  
    timeout_fly_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Fly::run, this ) ); 
}
```

and

```
/* Bee */
class Bee { 
... 
deadline_timer timeout_bar_; 
char text_bee_;
Data *shared_data;

Bee::Bee(io_service &io, Data *data): timeout_bee_(io, seconds(2)), shared_data(data)
{ 
    timeout_bee_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Bee::loop, this ) );  
}

Bee::loop(void) 
{ 
     std::cout << "Running Bee forever" << std::endl;

     shared_data->setMember( "I write something else here" );

     timeout_bee_.expires_at( timeout_bee_.expires_at() + seconds(2) );
     timeout_bee_.async_wait( boost::bind( &Bee::loop, this ) ); 
 }
```

Inside those classes (**Bee** and **Fly**) you can point to the same object of type **Data** using pointers.
In both you can call methods and set or get members of the class Data.
Since both classes are incapsulated inside a thread you need to use a mutex inside **Data** to avoid that the same ressource or variable is going to be write by both threads at the same time.

I don't pretend to have the best design one can develop. But it works and - despite the use of pointers and other things - it works and it is really easy to understand and to follow the basic idea behind such design.

I hope it can help other people, which have the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**Before handling the question of OOP design, a little correction:**

In the constructor you pass the `bee` by reference to the original object.  This would allow sharing.   However, your `bee_` member is a plain value.  So your constructor will copy the original object.  You would hence not work on a shared value, but on its clone, leaving the original unchanged.

Make it a reference, or a pointer.

**Design issue**

Your design needs to be improved:  bee and fly are two independent objects, that exist independently.  By providing at construction a pointer to the other object, you create a dependency between the two, which doesn't correspond to the reality.  I.e. you can no longer create a fly without the bee.  And How will you do if you want the `bee` object to access to the `fly` object ?!

**Alternative**

You could use this kind of reciprocal pointer, but you should not populate it at construction. You should prefer a separate setter. As the setting of both objects should match, you'd need to implement in both setters the setting in the reciprocal object, in a way to avoid endless recursion.  A cleaner apporach could use a friend function that would set a mutual link.

```
class Fly { 
    Bee *bee_;
    ...
    friend void peer(Bee&b, Fly&f);  
}; 
class Bee { 
    Fly *fly_;
    ...
public: 
    ...
    friend void peer(Bee&b, Fly&f);  
}; 
void peer(Bee&b, Fly&f) { 
    b.fly_ = &f; 
    f.bee_ = &b; 
    // this is simplified:  in realit you'd check if each object if already 
    // bound, and if yes, it would first reset the binding of the old corresponding pointer.  
}
```

In both case, you could then pass data between the objects by calling functions from the peer object, as you've
done with `getTextInBee()`

Another approach could be to have a third object to represent a message/event queue:

- The `bee` and the `fly` could then register as observer using the [observer design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to this queue.
- Any bee or fly could post a message to this queue
- The queue would then notify the objects of new messages.

This design is a little more complex than the previous one, but it could work with any number of objects (e.g. 2 bees & 5 flies).

This kind of implementation could be improved further by making `Fly` and `Bee` both inherit from the same base class `FlyingInsect`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap anything that is shared between these 2 classes in a separate object, and have the two classes access pointers for that object.
If there will be a race condition both Fly and Bee using data at same time, you can use a mutex.

Comment: Your idea is really good. But I'm experiencing some problem trying to implement it. Could you please provide an example? Even if not yours...it would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment, you can make a class that contain the shared data and have a pointer for it in each of these two classes. Create an object from the shared information and pass it to them. If you are still in that problem let me now.

Comment: Yeah, I m still there trying to understand and improve my concept. Any example is really welcome